# how to add a human sound to the utterances of a custom intent in alexa skills?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

A handler to be invoked when the skill receives an intent request with the name HelloWorldIntent, and the HelloWorldInten's utterances will have the  crying sound of a baby. ***How do I put the crying sound in the utterances?***

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trigger Alexa without the wake a word (generally “Alexa”) unless you are already in a skill session. In both these cases intents are mapped according to the  utterances given in the interaction model.

Unless you can convert *“baby-crying”* sound into words, then you won’t be able to trigger a custom intent. Also as of now there is no option to upload sample utterance as audio files.

One thing which you can try is `AMAZON.FallbackIntent` which gets triggered when Alexa is unable to find a proper intent match. When you are in a skill session and if you make a *“baby-crying”* sound, 
`AMAZON.FallbackIntent` might get triggered, but there is no guarantee.

---

**Responding with custom sounds**.

If you want to respond with a *“baby-crying”*  sound then you have to use `SSML` to add audio source to your response. You can either add a mp3 source of *"baby crying"* in audio tag like this:

```
<speak>
    The baby is about to cry.
    <audio src='https://yoursoundsource.com/path/to/baby_crying.mp3'/>
</speak>
```

### [Alexa Skills Kit Sound Library](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/ask-soundlibrary.html)

Luckily for you, there is an in built library of sounds for Alexa and *"baby crying"* sound is already there. So, ou don't have to upload one. Just use the audio source in your response `SSML`.
The following sounds are listed under [Human Sounds](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/human-sounds.html#human-sounds).

baby big cry (1)

```
<audio src='soundbank://soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_baby_big_cry_01'/>
```

baby cry (1)

```
<audio src='soundbank://soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_baby_cry_01'/>
```

baby cry (2)

```
<audio src='soundbank://soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_baby_cry_02'/>
```

baby fuss (1)

```
<audio src='soundbank://soundlibrary/human/amzn_sfx_baby_fuss_01'/>
```

In case you want to upload your own, make sure that your audio file meets the criteria.
More on SSML `audio` tag [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio)

Comment: OP asked about using the crying sound in utterances, not Alexa's response.